# How to fix leaky/clogged drain vent?

Tags: plumbing

When tearing out our bathroom to remodel it, we discovered a leak in the vent from the downstairs bathroom. You can't see it in the picture, but the leak begins at the bottom of the coupler which is held tight by the metal band. There is no sign of water damage above the coupler.

There shouldn't be any water in this pipe at all so I'm worried something is backed up. It's been in this configuration for 40-ish years. There is some water damage, but not much (the floor is still solid). [image]

**How should I fix this? Should I be concerned that the vent is clogged and filling up?**

Comment: That pipe will have water in it every time it rains.  I think you can focus on the repair.

Comment: If this is a vent, it should not "fill up" with rainwater, right? It also should not fill with waste water from the house, right? Sounds like there is a blockage. But of course it should not leak even if it has water standing in it. Which problem should be dealt with first--the leaking or the blockage (if there is one)? When the OP has the joint opened up to repair the leak should he run water in to see if this indicates a blockage and run a snake from that point to see if he can clear it?

Comment: It hasn't rained in several days and there is a cap on the top of the vent above the roof so the water didn't come from the sky. That seems to point strongly to a clog. Please correct me if I'm not thinking about this right.